# Is chi blocking based of any actual martial arts?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

In Avatar and The Legend of Korra, chi-blocking seems to be a set of quick jabs which can paralyse and defend against benders.

But was it based of any real life martial arts, or was this just made up on the spot? Or was chi-blocking inspired from other sources such as other animes such as Naruto ect...

Answers are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Chi-Blocking as depicted in Avatar is a technique of martial attack designed to disrupt the flow of chi in a bender, as well as harming the nerve centers of the bender, preventing them from assuming the necessary postures for bending to occur. Nerve strike martial arts techniques have been known to exist and many such strikes exist in almost every martial art.

Chi (a form of spiritual energy is believed to be able to be manipulated through acupressure and acupuncture for health reasons) becomes the fuel for inner power techniques (in this case, bending or jutsus) that allow martial artists to perform superhuman feats.

- The manipulation of Chi, the inner lifeforce depicted in ancient Eastern medical and martial art practices is not a new idea and has been around for thousands of years.
- In real world martial arts, chi mastery was supposed to make it possible to perform devastating physical strikes by channeling chi and directing it into one's body. Breaking bricks or the Iron Body techniques (where a person becomes more difficult to injure) are supposed displays of such chi master and bodily control.
- Avatar and Naruto have taken an idea (chi meridians) used in in medicine and turned it into a way of tapping inner power for spectacular martial displays of bending or jutsu manipulation.
- In Avatar's chi-blocking techniques, this manipulation appears as a martial arts dedicated to nerve strikes which cause the victim to lose control of their limbs or reduced their mobility. While it was called chi-blocking, it appeared more as a means of making it difficult for benders to achieve the proper positions to bend effectively.
- To be fair, the strikes may have also been along meridians where chi is known to pass and disrupted the flow of chi, preventing benders from being able to guide, manipulate or channel their chi for quality bending.